# UE4 C++ Difference between Super::METHOD() and Super().METHOD()

Tags: c++

Whats the difference between Super::METHOD() and Super().METHOD()?
Both work the same for me but i would like to know the difference and where i need it.

Comment: one is called on the instance and one is called on the type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much knowledge of UE4, but from this syntax I would say:
Super::METHOD() is calling to the Super class method in your object, but when calling Super().METHOD() you are creating a temporal Super() object were you call METHOD on.